# Element inside an array.map with different values

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

Want to use a React Selector inside an array.map with different values saving them in the state. However, they finally have the same value.

What I want to do is to have 4 selectors which values have to be different, but as they are rendering inside an array.map, they have the same value

Help will be much apreciated, Thanks!

[I want to have these selectors with different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFA4E.png)

```
{Object.keys(json).map((key) => (
    <th key={key + (+ new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999))}>                              
     <Select
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      options={options}
      />
      </th>
      ))}
```

Comment: What do you mean "they finally have the same value"? Can you also include all relevant code and assets, and clearly state what the problem/issue is, what you've tried to resolve it, and what the actual and expected results are?

Comment: What libraries are you using? What is this json that you are trying to map? Please provide more details.

Comment: I want to chage a mapped json from csv data key names, with these selectors, but thes have the same value

Comment: of course they all have the same value? You are mapping the keys of json but in the end you're always rendering a <Select> with the same selected value, the same onChange function and the same list of options to choose

Comment: So how could i fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dream-85m60?file=/src/App.js:0-894)
A bit difficult to understand exactly what you want, but I will take a stab.

First, you need to ensure your "key" attribute remains the same between renders to ensure the component does not unmount/remount. React uses the key to determine if a component must unmount, or be updated.

second, since you are rendering options out of an array, you need to have state to hold any number of options, and provide a method to update that array state for each options.

That means having state and a mutation function that looks like this

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});

  const handleChange = (key, value) => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, [key]: value };
    });
  };
```

Then each option will update a piece of state depending on the "key" value from your json object. The value of the Select will also be fetched from state using this key. This also shows why this key should remain constant between renders.

```
   {Object.keys(json).map((key) => (
       <th key={key} style={{ width: "200px" }}>
           <Select
               value={state[key]}
               onChange={(value) => handleChange(key, value)}
               options={options}
            />
        </th>
    )}
```

I am not sure what your `json`file looks like, but I mocked something up. It might be better to store this configuration in an array, and map the array instead of using the Object.Keys iterator over an object. But, will leave it as you had it.

the result is as follows

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";

const json = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3" };

const options = [
  {
    value: 0,
    label: "Option 1"
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: "Option 2"
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: "Option 3"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});

  const handleChange = (key, value) => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, [key]: value };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table columns>
        {Object.keys(json).map((key) => (
          <th key={key} style={{ width: "200px" }}>
            <Select
              value={state[key]}
              onChange={(value) => handleChange(key, value)}
              options={options}
            />
          </th>
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```